# IntelliJ - How to ignore whitespace during a global find/replace

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I'm trying to do a global find/replace on `jsp` files using Intellij but the spacing is different so when Intellij generates a regular expression it's different each time since the spacing is different each time (old site).

Currently I highlight the code, `Ctrl + F` and searcg for the reg expression that's generated.

How do I get Intellij to search for a chunk of code while ignoring the spaces?

Ex.

Searching for:

`\<head\>\n\<meta http\-equiv\=\"Content\-Type\" content\=\"text\/html\; charset\=iso\-8859\-1\" \/\>`

Will not return:

```
\<head\>\n          \<meta http\-equiv\=\"Content\-Type\" content\=\"text\/html\; charset\=iso\-8859\-1\" \/\>
```

Is there a way for Intellij to ignore that huge space?

Comment: Replace all spaces and `\n` (`\r`, too) with `\s+` to match any 1+ whitespace chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\s` character class will match any whitespace character, including `\n`. Combine this with `+` to match one or more spaces, or with `*` to match zero or more spaces.

This regex...

```
<head>\s*<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

...will match all of the following:

```
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

---

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

---

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```